# List all paths with a suffix in CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I would like to get all the paths that ends with a given suffix (like 'example/subpath/string') . Is there any simple way of doing it in Windows cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dir /ad /s /b c:\startingPoint | findstr /l /e /c:"example\subpath\string"
```

dir folders (`/ad`) from `c:\startingPoint` and below (`/s`) in bare format (`/b`). Filter the list with `findstr`, we only want the lines with the literal (`/l`) `"example\subpath\string"` (`/c`) at the end of the line (`/e`)

Adapt as needed

Comment: You should add the `/i` option. Also, although literal backslashes do not need to be escaped unless at end, it is a good idea to do so (easier to remember, and always works).